# ¿Cómo hacer un array asociativo en php a partir de dos campos mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, array, jsonarray

Tengo una tabla MySQL llamada 'enlaces' con dos campos: 'texto' y 'url'. Me gustaría crear un objeto json (en realidad, array asociativo) en php, a partir de una consulta de selección de esos dos campos.

El código es el siguiente:

```
<?php

//se estable conexión con la base de datos

$conexion = mysql_connect("localhost","root","******");

if (!$conexion) 
{
die("Falló la conexión con la base de datos.");
}


//se selecciona la base de datos

$seleccionbd = mysql_select_db("linkador",$conexion);



//se prepara la consulta

$consulta = "SELECT * FROM enlaces";


//se ejecuta la consulta

$resultado = mysql_query($consulta,$conexion);


//mediante el bucle while se muestran los resultados por fila


while($fila = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado)){

//como en el campo url tengo cada url como un gran string/cadena separado 
  por comas, lo fracciono dando lugar a un array de urls

$urls = explode(',',$fila['url']);


//creo el array de texto y su/s correspondiente/s url/s

$links = array($fila['texto'] => $urls);


echo json_encode($links);


}

?>
```

Al final obtengo algo como esto:

```
{"texto1":["url1","url2"]}{"texto2":["url3","url4"]}{"texto3":["url5","url6"]}
```

Y yo quiero que sea con esta estructura (un solo objeto/array, sin las llaves intermedias):

```
{"texto1":["url1","url2"], "texto2":["url3","url4"], "texto3":["url5","url6"]}
```

¿Por qué se duplican las llaves como varios objetos? ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? Espero su ayuda. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas creando varios Json que imprimes uno tras otro. La asignación a links la deberías hacer con `[]` y sacar el encode del `while`.

```
$links = array();
while($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
   $urls = explode(',',$fila['url']);
   $links[$fila['texto']] = $urls;
}
echo json_encode($links);
```

> La extensión de php [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) es obsoleta, se recomienda usar [mysqli](/questions/tagged/mysqli) ó [pdo](/questions/tagged/pdo).

Comment: Hola, Sal. No entiendo cómo hacer la asignación a $links con []. ¿Podrías escribir la sintaxis? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Solo recuerda que deberá cambiar también su conexión, si le pones que use el método mysqli_fetch_assoc

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, Sal. Ahora sí se solucionó. Lo que es estar atascado horas y horas sin ser capaz de obtener lo que uno quiere obtener con el código, y que luego venga un experto o alguien que sepa más -en este caso, tú-, y en un pis pas dé con la solución. Es muy alentador. Un saludo.